# Identify individual organization that visits my website - PHP

Tags: php, ip, tracking

There are a few services (at least here in Sweden) which let you identify a company that has visited a particular website. By checking an IP address, I know that you can get information such as the ISP and an organization, but the organization isn't necessairily the one that visited.

So my question is: How does this work?

(PS. I recently received a call from one of these companies after I visited their website, even though my IP here at the office isn't connected to my company in any way.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

[DNSStuff - Whois](http://private.dnsstuff.com/tools/whois.ch?ip=)

And aside from that you just need to use Curl to get the contents of the website and sort out the data you need.

Unless they provide an API.

Comment: Could this be used to track an individual person at a company? In that case, how?

Comment: Well, no. There's no way to track an individual in a company. Since the entire company - or at least the ones in the same building - will be having the same external IP.

Comment: Could it be done by cross-referencing or something? While the person is online you will be able to see information about the computer. Is there any way to find who is the owner?

Comment: If you get the MAC Address of the computer and then go to the office and find out which person is sitting by that computer, then yeah.